# Activerecord find_by_id strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Consider I have a show method in controller like this:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        thing = Thing.find_by_id(params[:id])
        render json: 'Not Found', status: :not_found and return if !thing
        render json: thing.to_json, status: :ok
    end
end
```

There is only 1 record in database with id=1.

Now, here is my test:

1. When I call /things/1 I can get the record.
2. When I call /things/2 I get 404.
3. When I call /things/a1 I get 404.
4. When I call /things/1a I am expecting error but it gives me record with id=1.

Is #4 normal? How to prevent that?

Rails Version: 4.2.6

Answer (score 2):

`.find_by_id()` method is converting passed in argument to integer and because `1a.to_i` is `1`, it is returning a record value.

If you want to prevent that, you'd have to check that the passed in `param[:id]` contains only digits.

```
'1a' !~ /\D/                # false
'12' !~ /\D/                # true

# So, use it in the if
params[:id] !~ /\D/
```

Comment: If i make the data type for id as string, then find_by_id won't to_i the param right? E.g. /things/1a2b and /things/3c4d will find exact match for 1a2b and 3c4d?

Answer (score 1):

Because type of id is integer, so active record will convert it to integer before create query string by using `to_i` function. If you don't want user go to details with link like this, there are many ways to prevent, some e.g for you:

1.Validate params[:id] is number in `ThingsController`

2.Create class method `find_by_id` in `Thing`

```
class class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base   
  def self.find_by_id(id)
    validate_type_id!(id) # Have to define the function to raise not found exception if invalid format type
    super   
  end
end
```